# checkout out local, which path should I use

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, windows-server-2008, bamboo

I have a mercurial repository that is not accessible by Http. I can't figure out how I should configure the path in my continuous integration tool (bamboo), before my repo was hosted co-located and I had to access it bij http (that was easy)

The documentation states that the path should be in the following format:

```
file://local/filesystem/path[#revision]
```

my repo is on `d:\Repository\myproject`. I tried thinks like `file://local/D:/Repository/myproject` , `file://D:/Repository/myproject`, `file://D:/Repository/myproject#default` and `"file://local/D/project/myproject"` , but I got the error

```
abort: file:// URLs can only refer to localhost stdout:
```

How should my path look like?

Comment: Also try `file:///filesystem/path` (omitting hostname entirely) that works in most URL settings too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out on Windows, you should use the following format:

```
"file://localhost/C:/path/to/my svn repo"
```